# Output in spite of fatal error

Tags: php, object, fatal-error

Here my function and its call:

```
function checkAccess($_cuser, $_user){
    print($_cuser->getValue("usr_id"));

    $access=true;

    if($_cuser->getValue("usr_id")==$_user && $access) {
        $access=true;
    }

    if($_cuser->viewAllLists()==false && $_cuser->getValue("usr_id")!=$_user && $access) {
        $access=false;
    }

    if($_cuser->viewAllLists()==true && $_cuser->getValue("usr_id")!=$_user && $access){
        $access=true;
    }

    return $access;
}


checkAccess($gCurrentUser, $_REQUEST["user"]);
```

I always get the error "**Fatal Error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in ... on line 1**" but the the **"User Id: 14" is being printed anyways**. This just does not seem very logic to me. What could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: What does `checkAccess` look like?

Comment: Where you have `getValue();` function?

Comment: You likely have multiple calls to `checkAccess()` and one is failing.

Comment: Post all the code (NOT in the comments section!) - it's difficult to guess where did you mess up ;P

Comment: Please edit your initial post with the code instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Also, you should show us which line triggers the error (line 14)

Comment: Jason was absolutely right i just called it multiple times without knowing it.
I somehow failed with require and require_once.
But thanks to all of you (: